# How to generate a chart automatically?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I need to generate a chart that has a format like this.
[image: WantedChart]

Using different months from January to December (x-axis) to the number of times it occurred within the month(y-axis), using the data below.
[image: Data]

- The data is formatted into "Month,dd,yyyy" but its original data is written as "yyyy-mm-dd".

I tried this code below to generate a graph, but

1) it creates a new sheet and generates the graph in the new sheet. I need it in the existing sheet.

2) as shown in the picture above, no data is generated, it is just a blank chart.

```
Sub GenerateChart()

Dim NumMonthChart As Chart
Set NumMonthChart = Charts.Add

With NumMonthChart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Control").Range("H2:H100")
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Number of errors in a month"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Month"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Number Of Errors"
End With

End Sub
```

I would like to get data from my arrays, e.g. month and the data is always entered in new worksheets thus there won't be an exact name of the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this below:

```
Sub GenerateChart()

' You can add Shape type chart if you want to place a chart within a sheet
Dim NumMonthChart As Object
Set NumMonthChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart

With NumMonthChart.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range("Control!H2:H100")
    .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Control!$H$2:$H$100"
    ' Specify your range for Y Values
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Control!$F$2:$F$100"  
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Number of errors in a month"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Month"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Number Of Errors"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer but charts are still not appearing

Comment: Is your range correct ? Are all data in "Control" Sheet ?

Comment: hi, sorry actually i would like to get data from my arrays,  e.g month and the data is always generated in new worksheets thus there won't be an exact name of the sheet...

Comment: maybe a better solution would be to pass the name of the worksheet as an argument when calling this method e.g. `Sub GenerateChart(srcSheet as Worksheet)` and then `.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & srcSheet.Name & "!$H$2:$H$100"`